# unable to pass array variable to select field in metabox

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm using this code to get data from text type metabox.. This will create an array

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'locations_add');
    $prefix = 'nilgiris_';
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($the_query->have_posts()):


        while ($the_query->have_posts()):
        $the_query->the_post();
        $l_names[] = rwmb_meta($prefix . 'l_name');
         $lo_name = array();
        foreach( $l_names as $l_namea ){
            $lo_name[] = array(
            $l_namea => $l_namea
            );
              }
        endwhile; 
        endif;
```

My problem is that when using the `wp_query` function along with metabox the metabox will not load..

Hers is the entire code

```
    <?php 

   $args = array('post_type' => 'locations_add');
    $prefix = 'nilgiris_';
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($the_query->have_posts()):


        while ($the_query->have_posts()):
        $the_query->the_post();
        $l_names[] = rwmb_meta($prefix . 'l_name');
         $lo_name = array();
        foreach( $l_names as $l_namea ){
            $lo_name[] = array(
            $l_namea => $l_namea
            );
              }
        endwhile;   

        endif; 


add_filter('rwmb_meta_boxes', 'website_register_meta_boxes');

function website_register_meta_boxes($meta_boxes) {

    $prefix = 'nilgiris_';

     $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'location_types',
        'title' => __('location name', $prefix),
       'post_types' => array('locations_add'),
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'autosave' => true,
        // List of meta fields
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name' => __('Enter Location Name', $prefix),
                'id' => "{$prefix}l_name",
                'desc' => __('Enter name', $prefix),
                'type' => 'text',
            //'clone' => true,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'location_types',
        'title' => __('location name', $prefix),
        'post_types' => array('Hotels'),
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'autosave' => true,
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name' => __('Enter Location Name', $prefix),
                'id' => "{$prefix}H_name",
                'desc' => __('Enter name', $prefix),
                'type' => 'text',
                        ),    

            array(
                'name' => __('Checkbox list', '$prefix'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}H_list",
                'type' => 'select',

                **'options' => $lo_name,**
            ),                     

        ),
    );


    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

Comment: This really isn't a complete question.  There's no reason given for why the page won't load and a bunch of code missing so it'd hard to know where to begin.  It's better if you can post a working sample.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok..ill add the complete code

Comment: @Tibrogargan can u take a look at this now